# Unable to install Netflix

Tags: apt, wine, ppa

I have tried to install Netflix but I get stuck

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

after the 3rd command I get a disclaimer but do not know how to pass it to continue the installation it is as follows:

```
 | 3. COPYRIGHT. All title and copyrights in and to the SOFTWARE PRODUCT (including but not limited to any images, text, and "applets"         
 │ incorporated into the SOFTWARE PRODUCT), the accompanying printed materials, and any copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT are owned by            
 │ Microsoft or its suppliers. The SOFTWARE PRODUCT is protected by copyright laws and international treaty provisions. Therefore, you         
 │ must treat the SOFTWARE PRODUCT like any other copyrighted material.                                                                        
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ 4. U.S. GOVERNMENT RESTRICTED RIGHTS. The SOFTWARE PRODUCT and documentation are provided with RESTRICTED RIGHTS. Use, duplication, or      
 │ disclosure by the Government is subject to restrictions as set forth in subparagraph (c)(1)(ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and         
 │ Computer Software clause at DFARS 252.227-7013 or subparagraphs (c) (1) and (2) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted Rights     
 │ at 48 CFR 52.227-19, as applicable. Manufacturer is Microsoft Corporation/One Microsoft Way/Redmond, WA 98052-6399.                         
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ LIMITED WARRANTY                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ NO WARRANTIES. Microsoft expressly disclaims any warranty for the SOFTWARE PRODUCT. The SOFTWARE PRODUCT and any related documentation      
 │ is provided "as is" without warranty of any kind, either express or implied, including, without limitation, the implied warranties or       
 │ merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose, or noninfringement. The entire risk arising out of use or performance of the             
 │ SOFTWARE PRODUCT remains with you.                                                                                                          
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ NO LIABILITY FOR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES. In no event shall Microsoft or its suppliers be liable for any damages whatsoever (including,       
 │ without limitation, damages for loss of business profits, business interruption, loss of business information, or any other pecuniary       
 │ loss) arising out of the use of or inability to use this Microsoft product, even if Microsoft has been advised of the possibility of        
 │ such damages. Because some states/jurisdictions do not allow the exclusion or limitation of liability for consequential or incidental       
 │ damages, the above limitation may not apply to you.                                                                                         
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ MISCELLANEOUS                                                                                                                               
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ If you acquired this product in the United States, this EULA is governed by the laws of the State of Washington.                            
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ If this product was acquired outside the United States, then local laws may apply.                                                          
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ Should you have any questions concerning this EULA, or if you desire to contact Microsoft for any reason, please contact the Microsoft      
 │ subsidiary serving your country, or write: Microsoft Sales Information Center/One Microsoft Way/Redmond, WA 98052-6399.                     
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │ Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fontpack/eula.htm                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                             
 │                                                                  <Ok>                                                                       
 │                                                                                                                                          │  
 └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

please help me get past this

Answer (score 1):

You have to agree to the user agreement before you can install the Proprietary software that Netflix requires. Just hit the arrow keys, "Tab", "Esc", "q", or "PageUp"/"PageDown", until the "OK" is selected(I forget which keys are exactly the ones you need to press since it's been a while since I installed). Now press enter and the Installation should continue.

If that still doesn't work try pressing CTRL+C.

In the future ask the Developer directly on his Webpage for help. He often replies quite quickly, or many people in the comments probably already had your issue and have already gotten replies.

http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html

Also search for a similar question before asking your own. I recently answered another question just like this but since it's owner never voted my answer I can't mark yours as a duplicate.